# How to get min and max temp for the day, from 5 day weather forecast JS?

Tags: javascript, api, weather

I'm building web application who need to show 5 day weather forecast. I get data from https://openweathermap.org/forecast5 My idea is to put information for each day using data from api trough 8 indexes of array. Exuse my bad English, here is screenshot for better understanding - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJhtV.jpg Here is the API example - https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

As seen from screen shot the index 0 get weather data from last 3 hour loop (12, 15, 16 etc). In almost every case I get data for each day.

I can't understand how to get min and max value for each day. If data from today is from 15:00 at index 0, I can't get information before this time. I can get only temp between 15:00 and 00:00 o'clock.

For first day I get this information from API:

```
.list[0].dt_txt
.list[0].main.temp
.list[0].weather[0].description
```

for second 8, for third 16 and etc...

Comment: I would use the daily forecast api as it already contains the min and max temp for each day

Comment: This is next idea in my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested before, use the [history API](https://openweathermap.org/history). To get the values for Munich for today + the next 4 days, use something like:

```
const getStartAndEndDateTimestamps = increment => {
    let startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + increment);
    startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    let endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + increment);
    endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);
    return {
        start: startDate.valueOf(),
        end: endDate.valueOf()
    };
};

const city = 'München';

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(increment => {
    const timestamps = getStartAndEndDateTimestamps(increment);
    const requestUrl = `http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=${encodeURIComponent(city)}&type=hour&start=${timestamps.start}&end=${timestamps.end}`;
    // get & process API data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the historical version of [API](https://openweathermap.org/api).
Perhaps other option could be creating server-side cookies or small database for historical values.

Comment: Hmm tanks I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

as per response got from given API

```
let weather=" assign response got from API to here";

let minArray=[];
let maxArray=[];  
for (let i of weather.list)  
 {  minArray.push(Number( i.main.temp_min)) ; 
    maxArray.push(Number(i.main.temp_max));  }
  console.log("min temp is "+ Math.min(...minArray));
 console.log("max temp is "+ Math.max(...maxArray));
```